# ruby on rails: ensure user must enter value before submittal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation

I have a form in rails using <%= form_for... %> and I was wondering what do I need to do so that the user has to submit values before submitting?

I have input field, radio buttons, and checkbox.

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :textfield %>
  <%= f.check_box :checkbox %>
  <%= f.radio_button :radiobutton %>
<% end %>
```

How do I tell my form that `:textfield`, `:checkbox`, and `:radiobutton` needs to be filled out or checked or something before submitting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [model validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#presence) to ensure that these attributes are present before saving the subsequent model:

You can operate on the *validation* level and pass attributes to be validated:

```
# app/models/user.rb
validates_presence_of :textfield, :checkbox, :radiobutton # or whatever actual attribute names you choose
```

Or, alternatively, you can specify validations to run for a model (many users now prefer this method):

```
# app/models/user.rb
validates :textfield, :presence => true # or `presence: true` in Ruby 1.9
validates :checkbox, :presence => true
validates :radiobutton, :presence => true
```

If any of these attributes are not filled in upon submission, an error on `save` will be thrown, which you can handle by rendering back to the action you submitted from.

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def create
    user = User.new(params[:user])
    if user.save
        # handle if successful
    else
        flash[:message] = "Something did not validate" # if using flash messages
        render :action => :new
    end
end
```

ALTERNATIVE:

If you truly want to validate your fields *prior* to submission, you can use a Javascript/jQuery validation library like [jQuery.validationEngine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine). These client-side libraries can enable you to entirely prevent form submission based on validation criteria – that is, if validation fails, the form is never posted via HTTP.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! `validates_presence_of` Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use clientside validation gem for this purpose. Check out its git repo [client_side_validation](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations)

Include ClientSideValidations in your Gemfile

```
gem 'client_side_validations'
```

Then run the install generator

```
rails g client_side_validations:install
```

This will install the initializer:

```
config/initializers/client_side_validations.rb
```

Then uncomment the some lines from this file according to your requirements.
Add this to your application.js file

```
//= require rails.validations
```

and change the form_tag as:

```
<%= form_for @user, :validate => true do |f| %>
```